# Display em-dash on Amazon S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3

I have static HTMLs served by Amazon S3.

However `&mdash;` is not shown as —.

How do I display them?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser needs to recognize that the file is written in HTML.

If you are uploading the file to S3 via the S3 Management Console, use a filename ending in `.htm` or `.html`. This will set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`.

Alternatively, if you are programmatically creating the file, set the metadata on the object of:

- Key: `Content-Type`
- Value: `text/html`

Answer (score -1):

You can [configure special characters](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/affinity-docs/help/designer/English.lproj/index.html?page=/Text/specialCharacters.html?title=Special%20characters).

Hope this helps!